# How to resolve relative url with Jsoup?

Tags: java, url, jsoup

Hi I have a problem with Jsoup.

I scrape a page and get a lot of urls. Some of those are relative urls like: `"../index.php"`, `"../admin"`, `"../details.php"`.

I use `attr("abs:href")` to get the absolute url, but this links are rendered like `www.domain.com/../admin.php`

I would like to know if this is a bug.

Is there a way to get the real absolute path with jsoup? how can I solve this?

I have tried also with `absurl("href")`, but not working.

Comment: I'm not sure what jSoup is, or what relation it has to ColdFusion. However, if you're using `cfhttp`, you can add `resolveurls="true"` and `cfhttp` will return you the full absolute URL for links and srcs.

Comment: how is this related to php and coldfusion?

Comment: This question is related in general to all programming language. Jsoup is a java library to parse html.

Comment: Can you post some more code of how you use jsoup here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

also a good option is to use the abs:href or abs:src attributes:

```
String relHref = link.attr("href"); // == "/"
String absHref = link.attr("abs:href"); // "http://jsoup.org/"
```

this is also described there:
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls

Answer (score 9):

If `element` contains a relative link you get the absolute link like this: `element.absUrl("href")`.

But you have to **set the base URI for your relative links before** (call  eg. `setBaseUri("http://www.myexample.com")` on your `Document` or `Element`).

**Make shure your base Uri is long enough!**

**Good:**

```
element.setBaseUri("http://www.example.com/abc/");
element.attr("href", "../b/here");
```

*returns:* `http://www.example.com/b/here`

**Bad:**

```
element.setBaseUri("http://www.example.com/abc/");
element.attr("href", "../../b/here");
```

*returns:* `http://www.example.com/../b/here`

--> your relative link is too long for you base uri!