# Url is not returning the correct html in a webpage (for my Java crawler)

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup, data-collection

I want to download some images from a webpage, for that I was writing a crawler. I tested couple of crawlers for this page but none worked as I wanted.

In the first step, I collected the links of 770+ camera models (`parent_url`), then I was thinking of collecting images in each link(`child_urls`). However, the page is organized in such a way that `child_urls` are returning the same html as `parent_url`.

Here is my code to collect camera links:

```
public List<String> html_compiler(String url, String exp, String atr){
    List<String> outs = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        Elements links = doc.select(exp);
        for (Element link : links) {
            outs.add(link.attr(atr));
            System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr(atr));
        }
    } catch (IOException | SelectorParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return outs;
}
```

With this code, I collect the links

```
String expCam = "tr[class='gallery cameras'] > td[class='title'] > a[href]";
String url = "https://www.dpreview.com/sample-galleries?category=cameras";
String atr = "href";
List<String> cams = html_compiler(url, exp, atr); // This gives me the links of individual cameras

String exp2 = "some expression";
html_compiler(cams.get(0), exp2, "src"); // --> this should give me image links of the first
                                         //camera but webpage returns same html as above
```

How can I solve this problem? I'd love to hear about other pages which classified images according to camera models. (other than Flickr)

**EDIT:**
e.g. In java the following two links gives the same html.

https://www.dpreview.com/sample-galleries?category=cameras

https://www.dpreview.com/sample-galleries/2653563139/nikon-d1-review-samples-one

Comment: Can you try using the `abs:href` attr? [Take a look here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14205979/1992780).

Comment: @DavidePastore both are returning the same results, I don't think it is about the absolute link.

Comment: The second link seems to trigger some javascript in the browser which loads the pictures. Try to open both links with debugging tools in your browser. (ctrl+shift+Q in firefox) You have to find out how the picture links are created somewhere in the page source.

Comment: It sounds like the web server might be doing something strange.  It makes no sense that two links would return the same HTML, not unless: 1) The URL was invalid and what you are seeing is the 404 page response, 2) The site is a SPA (Single Page App), in which case all URLs would most likely return the app, or 3) The web server is filtering on the User-Agent to prevent bots. For 1, you need to fix your URL.  For 2, not sure what you need to do, but I doubt this is the issue.  For 3, you can "spoof" your user agent and see if that helps.

Comment: A little update to my last comment: The links on the first page have three attached javascript event handlers. One of them creates a `SampleGalleryV2` which controls the behaivor of the picture gallerie. Search the javascript files linked to the page for details.

Comment: @kaetzacoatl: Yes, I found it. `$(document).ready(function() {            SampleGalleriesControllerV2({"galleryId":"","imageId":""});        });` the gallery ID is in the link but how can I obtain the image IDs? Do you think it is fetching the image IDs from database?

Comment: @CodeChimp I'm not sure if it is any one of them (definitely not 1 or 2) but I can try spoofing. Could you direct me a little about how I can spoof?

Comment: @smttsp You would simply create the HTTP request w/ a `User-Agent` that is a legit browser.  You can use something from [this list](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand how to get the image links, it's important to know how the page loads in a browser. If you click the gallerie link, a javascript event handler will be triggered. The created image viewer then loads the images from the data server. The image links are requested via javascript and thus not visible by just parsing the html. The request URL for the image links is `https://www.dpreview.com/sample-galleries/data/get-gallery` to get the images in the gallerie you have to add the gallerie id. The gallerie id is provided by the `href` attribute of the gallerie links. The links look like `https://www.dpreview.com/sample-galleries/2653563139/nikon-d1-review-samples-one`. In this case `2653563139` is the gallerie id. Take the link given above and add the gallerie id with `?galleryId=2653563139` to the end of the URL to get a json object containing all data needed to create the gallerie. Look for the `url` fields in the `images` array to get your images.

To summarize:

The link you get from the `href` attribute: https://www.dpreview.com/sample-galleries/2653563139/nikon-d1-review-samples-one

The gallerie id: 2653563139

The request url: https://www.dpreview.com/sample-galleries/data/get-gallery

The json object you need: https://www.dpreview.com/sample-galleries/data/get-gallery?galleryId=2653563139

The urls you are looking for inside the json object: `"url":"https://3.img-dpreview.com/files/p/TS1800x1200~sample_galleries/2653563139/7864344228.jpg"`

And finally your picture link: https://3.img-dpreview.com/files/p/TS1800x1200~sample_galleries/2653563139/7864344228.jpg

Comment if you want further explanation.

Comment: This is very nice explanation. The number of images in the link is matching with the number given in the gallery link, so it seems pretty solid solution. Thanks