# Extracting multiple links within a specific class

Tags: java, jsoup

```
<div class="customer"><a href='view.php?customer=1234' class=''></div>
<div class="customer"><a href='view.php?customer=1235' class=''></div>
<div class="customer"><a href='view.php?customer=1236' class=''></div>
```

In this example, would there be any way to extract the href links within the customer class, without having to re-parse the html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve relative url with Jsoup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041676/how-to-resolve-relative-url-with-jsoup)

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a better way, I think this works...

```
        Elements links = doc.select("div.customer a[href]");

        String absHref;
        for (Element link : links) {
            absHref = link.attr("abs:href");
            System.out.println(absHref);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Elements customerElements = doc.getElementsByTag("cutomer");
for(Element cutomer:customerElements){
     String link =customer.getElementsByTag("a").first().attr("href");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the below code.

```
Elements links = doc.select("div.customer a");
String linkUrl;
for (Element link : links) {
    linkUrl = link.attr("href");
    System.out.println(linkUrl);
}
```